# CakePHP 3 build complex join using query builder

Tags: cakephp, query-builder, cakephp-3.0

I need to add joins on the same tables dynamically... something like this:

```
// foreach ... as $id
$options['join']['T_Values' . $id] = [
    'type' => 'LEFT',
    'table' => 't_values',
    'conditions' => ['T_Values' . $id . '.t_id = T.id']
];
$options['join']['Values' . $id] = [
    'type' => 'LEFT',
    'table' => 'values',
    'conditions' => ['Values' . $id . '.id = T_Values' . $id . '.value_id', 'Values' . $id . '.v_id' => $id]
];

$options['fields']['x_' . $id] = 'Values' . $id . '.name';
// endforeach
```

The problem is that second value is not selected - it is null. This is simply solved by changing the second join type to 'INNER', but this is a problem since there are no results for existing record in T but missing record in T_Values. This type of join can handle it:

```
SELECT … 
FROM t T 
  LEFT JOIN (t_values T_Values2
    INNER JOIN values Values2 ON 
    (Values2.id = T_Values2.value_id AND Values2.v_id = 2)
  ) ON T_Values2.t_id = T.id  
  LEFT JOIN (t_values T_Values3 
    INNER JOIN values Values3 ON 
    (Values3.id = T_Values3.value_id AND Values3.v_id = 3)
  ) ON T_Values3.t_id = T.id  
WHERE T.k_id = 1 GROUP BY T.id
```

My question is: can this be achieved with query builder. Or better... can you suggest more simple way to do this? Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it "hard" way, if someone had similar problem:

```
$options['join'][] = [
    'type' => 'LEFT',
    'table' => '(t_values T_Values' . $id . ' INNER JOIN values Values' . $id . ' ON Values' . $id . '.id = T_Values' . $id . '.value_id AND Values' . $id . '.v_id = ' . $id . ')',
    'conditions' => ['T_Values' . $id . '.t_id = T.id']
];
```